# Google Analytics event goal not tracked

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, google-analytics

I've read a lot of the other common questions and I can't find any that apply.

I've created the following event in GA;

[image]

On form submission, I'm trying to mark a conversion for this event. I have the following code;

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    document.addEventListener( 'wpcf7mailsent', function( event ) {
        ga('send', 'event', 'Form', 'Submit', 'Contact');
        alert('done');
    }, false );    
});
```

I submit the form and the alert fires so the `eventListener` is working. Under realtime > conversions it shows the user active on the website which shows my GA tracking code has been added correctly. No conversion is added in GA.

I've also tried a GA callback when the event is hit, this never fired either.

Comment: What GA code do you use for pageview? gtag.js or analytics.js?

Comment: I just copied the snippet from the analytics dashboard, although the source code displays the following url

`https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-XXXXXXXXX-1`

Answer (score 1):

If you use gtag.js in snippet, you need to use this library for events too.

```
gtag('event', 'aaa', {
  'event_category' : 'bbb',
  'event_label' : 'ccc'
});
```

See documentation: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/events?hl=en